# Function like `setcar` that doesn't change the value of the input function?

Tags: list

Early beginner here. I'm looking for a function that takes a list and changes only its first element, using some function or other. I realize `setcar` sort of does that, but it also changes the initial list. Thus if I have

```lisp
(setq mylist '("Red" "Green" "Blue"))
```

and then run

```lisp
(setcar mylist (downcase (car mylist))
```

the value of `mylist` will change to `("red" "Green" "Blue")`.

What I'm looking for, though, is a function that only outputs the value that `setcar` will set `mylist` to but does not change the value of `mylist`.

I realize I could do, e.g.

```lisp
(setq mynewlist mylist)
(setcar mynewlist (downcase (car mynewlist))
```

and get essentially the same result. But I wanted to know if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: Ask your question about a variable as a separate question, please. One question per question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're asking for a function that returns a new list whose car is a value you provide and whose cdr is a copy of the cdr of the original list. That way, there is no modification of the original list, and the resulting list shares no structure with the original.

```lisp
(defun foo (new-car-val xs)
  "..."
  (cons new-car-val (copy-sequence (cdr xs))))

(foo (downcase (car mylist)) mylist)
```

---

By the way, this is *not* what you want:

```lisp
(setq mylist '("Red" "Green" "Blue"))

(setq mynewlist mylist)
(setcar mynewlist (downcase (car mynewlist)))
```

That modifies the original list, `mylist`, *and* `mynewlist`.  They are the **same** list.

If you don't want to share list structure, use `copy-sequence`.

See nodes [car, cdr, cons](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/car-cdr-_0026-cons.html) and [List Implementation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/List-Implementation.html) of manual *Intro to Emacs Lisp Programming*.

---

Update, from the comments:

Q: So am I right in thinking that `(setq var1 var2)` doesn't 'store' the current value of `var2` but rather 'tells' `var1` to always point to whatever `var2` is pointing to? Maybe I'm mixing too many metaphors here.

A: Yes, depending on what you mean. It sets the value of `var1` to whatever the value of `var2` is - the **actual thing**, not a copy. If the value of `var2` is a list, then the value of `var1` is set to that **same** list, not a copy.

Comment: So much to learn! Your answer just made me realize there are very many things about lists I do not understand. I need to do my homework better.

Comment: So am I right in thinking that `(setq var1 var2)` doesn't 'store' the current value of `var2` but rather 'tells' `var1` to always point to whatever `var2` is pointing to? Maybe I'm mixing too many metaphors here...

Comment: Yes, depending on what you mean. It sets the value of `var1` to whatever the value of `var2` is - the *actual thing*, not a copy. If the value of `var2` is a list, then the value of `var1` is set to that *same* list, not a copy.